# What is the best abilities modding system that you encounter in games?

Tags: architecture, modding

I'm thinking about designing an abilities system (as in a moba game).

Most important goal is to be able to easily create new abilities in the editor, with a low learning curve (ultimate goal: simple visual constructor, without any programming)

I'm searching for existing production systems, which allow to mod abilities, to analyze their design decisions.

By now, I explored DOTA2 system ([tutorial >>](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Dota_2_Workshop_Tools/Scripting/Abilities_Data_Driven)) and SC2 system ([tutorial >>](http://www.hiveworkshop.com/forums/trigger-gui-galaxy-ai-scripts-657/triggers-scripting-mechanics-starcraft-ii-209487/)), because of their success in modding community.

What other good abilities systems do you know, that are worth considering?

Thanks!

Comment: The point of question is - gather examples of ready, production systems. I want to analyze them to find some good design decisions. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Link collections aren't really a good fit for this format unfortunately. This site is aimed at questions that have a single or very few definite answers.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden Well a list of links related to one specific question could be working, no ? Since the question is well defined "Which good abilities system are made in games ?"

Comment: @Artyom Running short on time but I think UDK got an "already-made" moba project, with some code for abilities, and everything one would need to start a MOBA quickly... Even if it's not a real game, you could get some precise informations on how you can get a strong ability system

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden question can be reformulated as "production examples of abilities systems, available to public through modding, and their pros and cons"

Comment: That's still asking for a list. List-generation questions are not on-topic here either.